# Make use of Prize Enum and extension in Swift

Tags: swift

Using http://online.swiftplayground.run/ - this was my original implementation:

```
import Foundation

let IPHONE = "iphone"
let IPAD = "ipad"
let MACBOOK = "macbook"
let IMAC = "imac"
let NOTHING = "nothing"

let prizes: [String] = [IPHONE, IPAD, MACBOOK, IMAC, NOTHING];

func pickRandomPrize(prizes: Array<String>) -> String {
    let randomPrize: String = prizes.randomElement()!
    return randomPrize
}

class PrizeAnnouncer {
    let prizeWon: String;
    init(prizeWon: String) {
        self.prizeWon = prizeWon
    }
    func announce() {
        if prizeWon == NOTHING {
            return print("You've won... nothing")
        }

        print("Congratulations! You've won an \(prizeWon)")
    }
}

let randomPrize = pickRandomPrize(prizes: prizes)
let announcer = PrizeAnnouncer(prizeWon: randomPrize)
announcer.announce()
```

I did a different version leveraging Enums below.

```
import Foundation

enum Prize: String, CaseIterable {
  case iphone
  case ipad
  case macbook
  case imac
  case nothing
}

let prizes: [Prize] = Prize.allCases

func pickRandomPrize(prizes: [Prize]) -> Prize {
    let randomPrize: Prize = prizes.randomElement()!
    return randomPrize
}

class PrizeAnnouncer {
    let prizeWon: Prize;
    init(prizeWon: Prize) {
        self.prizeWon = prizeWon
    }
    func announce() {
        if prizeWon == Prize.nothing {
            return print("You've won... nothing")
        }

        print("Congratulations! You've won an \(prizeWon)")
    }
}

let randomPrize = pickRandomPrize(prizes: prizes)
let announcer = PrizeAnnouncer(prizeWon: randomPrize)
announcer.announce()
```

I am using this as a chapter of a book that introduces people interested in software engineering - and Swift is one of those considerations.

Each chapter has the following sections and uses code examples of the standard library:

- Language introduction
- Code example
- Use cases
- Did you know

Comment: "this version doesn't work" -- can you be more specific?

Comment: You aren't really describing what you think is wrong -- but I took a guess below.  Generally, you should put all of the information needed to answer the question in the question itself (not a link to somewhere else)

Comment: To nitpick (because you intend to put this in a book).  Typical swift code would use lowercase enums (or mixed case).  If you do that, you don't even need to assign the strings because the default string is the case name itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write `all` for `CaseIterable`.  It's already implemented and called `allCases`.

But, your implementation would not work -- you shouldn't put a case in the switch. There is no way to implement it without the `CaseIterable` interface except something like this:

`return [.IMAC, .IPHONE, .IPAD, .MACBOOK, .NOTHING]`

(I know you got it to work this way -- with a switch and fallthroughs, but it's very strange Swift code -- I definitely don't recommend it)

As you can see, that's error prone (you have to remember to update it if you add a case).  This is why `CaseIterable` exists.

Comment: Thanks! Updated question, happy with the solution?

Comment: Just a note to say that the original question did not use `allCases` -- because now this Q and A doesn't make sense :). I meant you should update it with your version of `all` -- anyway, glad it working for you!